# Missing Hindi font

Tags: fonts, languages

When I tried the following Tex file I got 
The font Lohit Hindi can not be found, although I installed the Typeset Devanagari. Same if I use sanskrit font or any other font from this type set. Any idea will be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm,left=0.5cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[iso]{datetime}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{Lohit Hindi}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\devanagarifont[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Sanskrit}
\newfontfamily\devtransl[Mapping=DevRom]{Times New Roman}




\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{0.5pt}
\chead{\textbf{\huge{Inform}}}
\lhead{\textbf{Test1}}
\rhead{\textbf{\normalsize{Sets}}}
\rfoot{\today \hspace{0.5pt} \currenttime}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}\lfoot{Some}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{supertabular}
\begin{document}
\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont
\tablehead
{
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\textbf{\foreignlanguage{sanskrit}{ग्रोस वोलयूम}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\textbf{नेट वाल्यूम}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\textbf{लेवल}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\textbf{तापमान}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\textbf{ऊलाज}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{42mm}}{\centering{\textbf{लास्ट अपडेटड}}}\\

& \multicolumn{1}{p{24.5mm}}{\centering{\textbf{गैलन}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\textbf{गैलन}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\textbf{सेन्टीमीटर}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{21mm}}{\centering{\textbf{सेन्टीग्रेड}}}
& \multicolumn{1}{p{16mm}}{\centering{\textbf{गैलन}}} & \\
\toprule
}

\begin{supertabular}{p{35mm}*{6}{r}}
\\ \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf {3001}}\\\\
\textbf{टेंक  2} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{SET1}\\
PROD 2& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(4,011 अधिकतम)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{प्रोडक्ट}} & 2,495.40 & 2,479.66 & 145.55 & 20.53 & 1,313.07 & 19/04/2012 15:00:23 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{Water}} & 1.79 & & 1.00 & & & \\\\ 
\textbf{टेंक  3} & \multicolumn{6}{l}{SET2}\\
PROD 3& \multicolumn{6}{l}{(4,011 अधिकतम)}\\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{प्रोडक्ट}} & 2,593.08 & 2,578.51 & 150.40 & 20.01 & 1,213.86 & 19/04/2012 15:00:23 \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{\textbf{SET3}} & 3.32 & & 1.51 & & & \\\\ 
\toprule[2pt]\\
\end{supertabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\setotherlanguage{hindi}`; and in the definition of `\devanagarifont` you have to use a font name (I suspect that "Sanskrit" isn't). Then in the argument of `\foreignlanguage` you have to use `hindi`, not `sanskrit`.

Comment: @egreg: Please the [rejected edit(s)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9411) for a comment to your comment.

Comment: @Chayo: Please register your account (using the same OpenID) to retain ownership of this question. Moderators are also able to merge separate accounts when ownership is lost. Edits to the original post was rejected based on the fact that it seemed like a comment; only possible by post owners and users with enough reputation.